# How can we generate the build file from VS.NET

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, makefile

If i have a VS.NET 2008 solution , and i want to export the build script so that i can use it to build the same application in another environment which does not have VS.NET, how can i extract this make or build script from the VS.NET ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your solution consists of .csproj or .vbproj, it is already a build script with MSBuild as the build engine. MSBuild comes with .NET framework, *not* with Visual Studio.

**Edit**:

You can launch MSBuild from the following locations:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.xxx
```

Starting with version 3.5 of the tool, you can [specify the target framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx) for which you want to build by specifying the "ToolsVersion" attribute on the project element.